# How to apply :loading in dynamically created button through v-for in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is the demo response from the API:

```
[
    {
      form_name: 'Form One',
      name: 'Peter',
      email: 'peter@email.com'
    },
    {
      form_name: 'Form Two',
      name: 'John',
      email: 'john@email.com'
    }
  ]
```

From that I built a form through `v-for`

```
<v-form 
   v-for="(item, index) in forms" :key="index"
>
  <v-btn
    :loading="saveLoading"
    @click="submit(item)"
  >
    submit
  </v-btn>
</v-form>
```

I set `saveLoading: false,` initially. In the `submit(item)` function, I was setting `saveLoading: true,` at first. Then at asynchronous function for POST method, I would turned that back to `false`. But, the problem is whenever, I click on the `submit` button in **one form**, **two `submit` buttons** in the **two form** got affected by loading state.
[image]

What to do to get the effect in one `submit` button for the current form only?

**[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/lr_73/pen/jOGwowr?editors=101)**

Answer (score 1):

```
<v-btn
    class="mr-4"
    :loading="saveLoading == index"
    @click="submit(item, index)"
  >


data: () => ({
    valid: true,
    saveLoading: -1,
 })


submit (formItem, index) {
      this.saveLoading = index
      console.log(formItem)
      // POST the formItem and make the saveLoading false in async then(), catch()
    },
```

It is not a very logical method, but this way you can solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your tricky solution. The problem is this when I click on one button, it gets the loading state. That's fine. But, whenever, I click on the other button in another form, the loading state from the first button has gone. If in any case, the API response is getting delayed after clicking the first button, and at that time if anyone clicks on the second button, the first button will be back to normal state even the response got stuck for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have only one variable. You could do `saveLoading1` to `saveLoadingN` but that's not very useful.

```js
var forms = [
    {
      form_name: 'Form One',
      name: 'Peter',
      email: 'peter@email.com'
    },
    {
      form_name: 'Form Two',
      name: 'John',
      email: 'john@email.com'
    }
  ]
function generate_computed_properties() {
  var states = {};
  for (let [ index, item ] of forms.entries()) {
    states['saveLoading_' + index] = false
  }
  return { states }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      forms: window.forms,
    ...generate_computed_properties()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit(index) {
        this.setLoadingState(index, true)
        setTimeout((function() {
          this.setLoadingState(index, false)
        }).bind(this), 1000)
    },
    setLoadingState(index, state) {
        this.states['saveLoading_' + index] = state
    },
  },
  computed: {
  },
  template: `<div>
    <form 
     v-for="(item, index) in forms" :key="index"
  >
      <h2>{{ item.form_name }}</h2>
      <button
        :disabled="states['saveLoading_' + index]"
        @click.prevent="submit(index)"
      >
        <span v-if="states['saveLoading_' + index]">Loading &hellip;</span>
        <span v-else>submit</span>
      </button>
  </form>
</div>`,
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

It'll be better to split your forms into subcomponents:

```js
var forms = [
    {
      form_name: 'Form One',
      name: 'Peter',
      email: 'peter@email.com'
    },
    {
      form_name: 'Form Two',
      name: 'John',
      email: 'john@email.com'
    }
  ];
var Button = Vue.component('v-btn', {
  props: [ 'loading' ],
  template: `<button :disabled="loading" @click="handleClick">
    <slot v-if="!loading"></slot>
    <span v-else>Saving &hellip;</span>
  </button>`,
  methods: {
    handleClick() {
      this.$emit('click');
    }
  }
})
  
var Form = Vue.component('v-form', {
  name: "Form",
  props: [ 'form' ],
  data() {
    return {
      saveLoading: false
    }
  },
  template: `<div>
    <h2>{{ form.form_name }}</h2>
    <v-btn
      :loading="saveLoading"
      @click="submit(form)"
    >
      submit
    </v-btn>
  </div>`,
  methods: {
    submit() {
      console.log('save')
      this.setLoading(true);
      setTimeout(this.setLoading.bind(this, false), 1000)
    },
    setLoading(isLoading) {
      this.saveLoading = isLoading
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { Form },
  data() {
    return {
      forms: window.forms
    }
  },
  template: `<div>
    <v-form 
     v-for="(item, index) in forms" :key="index" :form="item"
  >
  </v-form>
</div>`
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But, unfortunately, I am not in a state of changing the structure i.e. breaking into sub-components as the real scenario is not the same as this simple example. So, I was looking for a simple javascript example. For example, I was thinking if it's possible to take an array object dynamically something (for example, `loadingArr`) like this; `[{saveLoading: false, clearLoading: false}, {saveLoading: false, clearLoading: false}]`. Then, I can create the function like this way: `submit(item, index) {this.loadingArr[index].saveLoading = true}`

Comment: I added an alternative (first code block)

Comment: Based on the concept of your alternative solution, I have tried to simplify it according to my codes to make it working. But, it's not working. Can you please take a look on this CodePen demo: https://codepen.io/lr_73/pen/GRMvmZz?editors=10, modify it with that structure and provide the working CodePen link if possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating the forms from the api response, mean that in some way you are attaching the response to the Vue Data property. If so, you could easily enrich the objects of the array (the forms object) to have a isLoading property. So the result will be something like:

```
API RESPONSE
[
    {
      form_name: 'Form One',
      name: 'Peter',
      email: 'peter@email.com'
    },
    {
      form_name: 'Form Two',
      name: 'John',
      email: 'john@email.com'
    }
  ]
```

and store is as:

```
Stored object
[
    {
      form_name: 'Form One',
      name: 'Peter',
      email: 'peter@email.com',
      isLoading: false
    },
    {
      form_name: 'Form Two',
      name: 'John',
      email: 'john@email.com',
      isLoading: false
    }
  ]
```

Set the loading status in the submit(item) method:

```
submit(item){
   item.isLoading = true;
}
```

then you can use it by checking the value of isLoading on the form object, something on the lines of:

```
<v-form 
   v-for="(item, index) in forms" :key="index"
>
  <v-btn
    :loading="item.isLoading"
    @click="submit(item)"
  >
    submit
  </v-btn>
</v-form>
```

Comment: Thanks; that would be easy. But, I can't add a property at that array Objects. Becasue, I simply send that array of objects at the `submit` function. And the `POST` API can't accept those additional properties. So, I need to remove those properties at the time of submission. But, at `then()` callback how will I remove those when I send the data to the `POST` api before that callback and maintain the loading status at the callback? So, I may think of a new array that will be created dynamically matching with the length of the array from the response. Please, see my comment on 1st solution here.